# Write a “query-controlled” loop that will continue to input int values from the user?

Tags: c, loops

How do you write a “query-controlled” loop that will continue to input int values from the user, adding each to the int value sum, and then ask if the user has another value to input, until the user says that there are no more values. I don't know how to use do statements so I was thinking of using while loops or possibly a for loop. However, I don't know how to apply it in this situation. Could someone give me some pointers?

Comment: You should at least give it a shot on your own and share what you've tried. People won't just generally do your assignment for you here, but we're happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use a while loop, a do loop is just as easy and is what you should use in this case:

```
do
{
    // code to execute at least once
} while(condition);
```

Comment: Because we haven't learned it in the curriculum yet. I think my teacher just wants us to do it without a do loop.